# Unable to bind whole Chart to Frontend

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I am looking for a way to bind a whole Chart in my xaml. Not only one Series, but the whole Chart. This is due to my need to add multiple Series dynamically to the Chart.

**XAML:**

```
<chart:Chart DataContext="{Binding Path=FocusEnergyChart, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

**C#:**

```
public void DrawChart()
    {
        myChart = new Chart();

        LinearAxis xAxis = new LinearAxis();
        xAxis.Orientation = AxisOrientation.X;
        xAxis.Title = "Energy";
        LinearAxis yAxis = new LinearAxis();
        yAxis.Orientation = AxisOrientation.Y;
        yAxis.Title = "Focus";
        myChart.Axes.Add(xAxis);
        myChart.Axes.Add(yAxis);
        myChart.Title = "Focus Energy - Chart";
        foreach( string aKey in myGraphData.Keys)
        {
            BubbleSeries aSeries = new BubbleSeries();
            aSeries.Title = aKey;
            aSeries.ItemsSource = myGraphData[aKey];
            aSeries.DependentValuePath = "Focus";
            aSeries.IndependentValuePath = "Energy";
            aSeries.SizeValuePath = "Size";
            aSeries.SetResourceReference(Series.BackgroundProperty, "Background");
            aSeries.SetResourceReference(BubbleSeries.LegendItemStyleProperty, "CustomLegendItemStyle");
            aSeries.SetResourceReference(BubbleSeries.DataPointStyleProperty, "BubbleToolTipTemplate");
            myChart.Series.Add(aSeries);
        }
        base.OnPropertyChanged("FocusEnergyChart");
    }

    public Chart FocusEnergyChart
    {
        get { return myChart; }
    }
```

When i try to run this code it just shows me an empty ChartArea.

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you do here is add another chart as the `DataContext` of  your chart declared from XAML.

You can use a `ContentControl` and bind it's content to your chart created from code-behind:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=FocusEnergyChart}" />
```